# Three sql queries into one

Tags: php, sql, merge, pagination

I have following problem. I need to create pagination for this results. For create pagination I need to have only one while cycle (one sql query). Now I have three queries because of responsive div. I need preserve these three divs. Any ideas?

Thank you.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <?php
        require 'db.php';
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM dot where schva=1 order by id desc";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $item_num = 0;
        $num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($item_num % 3 == 0) {
                echo '<div class="box1 space30">
                  <div class="media">
                      <div class="media-left">
                         <a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '">
                          <img  src="img/chat.png" alt="...">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media-body">
                       <p><a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '" style="color:white;">' . $row['text'] . '</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="divider space20"></div>

                    <div class="txt">
                      <p>' . $row['nad'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            } ?>
            <?php
            $item_num++;
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <?php
        require 'db.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM dot where schva=1 order by id desc";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $item_num = 0;
        $num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($item_num % 3 == 1) {
                echo '<div class="box1 space30">
                  <div class="media">
                      <div class="media-left">
                         <a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '">
                          <img  src="img/chat.png" alt="...">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <p><a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '" style="color:white;">' . $row['text'] . '</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="divider space20"></div>

                    <div class="txt">
                      <p>' . $row['nad'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            } ?>
            <?php
            $item_num++;
        }
    ?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <?php
        require 'db.php';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM dot where schva=1 order by id desc";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $item_num = 0;
        $num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($item_num % 3 == 2) {
                echo '<div class="box1 space30">
                  <div class="media">
                      <div class="media-left">
                        <a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '">
                          <img  src="img/chat.png" alt="...">
                        </a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <p><a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '" style="color:white;">' . $row['text'] . '</a></p>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="divider space20"></div>

                    <div class="txt">
                      <p>' . $row['nad'] . '</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
            } ?>
            <?php
            $item_num++;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use mysqli_* not mysql_*.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any different solution?

Comment: you need to reorganise all the code. First you are "require-ing" the db.php multiple times. You need it only once. Second you are using the same query all the time. Why you dond use it one time and make all the logic in one while?

Comment: @NeelThakkar just answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, it's helpful. First use mysqli for query.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
    <?php
        require 'db.php';
        mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM dot where schva=1 order by id desc";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        $item_num = 0;
        $num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if ($item_num % 3 == 0) {
                //Code
            }elseif($item_num % 3 == 1){
                //Code
            }elseif($item_num % 3 == 2){
                //Code
            }

            $item_num++;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I need something like this:
`<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
//code
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
//code
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
//code
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try by using PDO:

**Version depends on the records in the database:**

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dot");
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<?php $item_num = 0; ?>

<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <?php if ($item_num % 3 == 0): ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($item_num % 3 == 1): ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($item_num % 3 == 2): ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $item_num++; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Version with a fixed amount of divs:**

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM dot");
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++): ?>
    <?php $item_num = 0; ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>

            <?php if ($item_num % 3 == 0): ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($item_num % 3 == 1): ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($item_num % 3 == 2): ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php $item_num++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need preserve three divs classes col-md-4 col-sm-12. Not only one.

Comment: Add to your question I want to get the input in HTML

Comment: I need something like this: `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> //while</div> <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> //while</div> <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> //while</div>`

Comment: If this value is to be fixed or be it as much as records in a table?

Comment: This only three divs must be fixed.

Comment: I think we are still don't understand. There have to be three fixed divs. Something like:
`<div><?php if ($item_num % 3 == 0): ?>
            <?php endif; ?></div><div><?php if ($item_num % 3 == 1): ?>
            <?php endif; ?></div><div><?php if ($item_num % 3 == 2): ?>
            <?php endif; ?></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help.

```
    $item_num = 0;
    $num_records = mysql_num_rows($result);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($item_num % 3 == 0) {
           echo '<div class="box1 space30">
              <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                     <a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '">
                      <img  src="img/chat.png" alt="...">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <p><a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '"
       style="color:white;">' . $row['text'] . '</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="divider space20"></div>

                <div class="txt">
                  <p>' . $row['nad'] . '</p>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }elseif($item_num % 3 == 1){
           echo '<div class="box1 space30">
              <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                     <a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '">
                      <img  src="img/chat.png" alt="...">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <p><a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '" 

                    style="color:white;">' . $row['text'] . '</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="divider space20"></div>

                <div class="txt">
                  <p>' . $row['nad'] . '</p>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }elseif($item_num % 3 == 2){
           echo '<div class="box1 space30">
              <div class="media">
                  <div class="media-left">
                     <a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '">
                      <img  src="img/chat.png" alt="...">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="media-body">
                    <p><a href="dot/' . $row['id'] . '" 
                 style="color:white;">' . $row['text'] . '</a></p>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="divider space20"></div>

                <div class="txt">
                  <p>' . $row['nad'] . '</p>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }

        $item_num++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I need something like this: `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> //code </div> <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> //code </div> <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12"> //code </div>`